# Are these two sentences gramatically correct?

Tags: grammar

(1) We sat on the corner of the restaurant talking how blessed we were for having a new house.

(2) We sat on the corner of the restaurant and talking how blessed we were for having a new house.

I somehow think that the sentences above are not correct or meaningful. Yet it's beyond me. Any correction is welcome.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, saying "on the corner of the restaurant" implies that you're not inside, but outside, perhaps sitting on top of the restaurant. Instead of "on", use "in" to say that you're inside the restaurant.

Additionally, in sentence 1, you need a word like "about" after "talking", and also a comma after "restaurant". So, it should be:

> (1) We sat in the corner of the restaurant, talking about how blessed we were for having a new house.

In sentence 2, because you're using "and", you don't need a comma, but instead of "talking", it should be "talked":

> (2) We sat in the corner of the restaurant and talked about how blessed we were for having a new house.

Answer (score 0):

You have the object of a preposition without the preposition in the phrase.  It should be "...talking *about* how..."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer doesn't provide any new information compared with other two answers already posted. I would advise you to visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

This is either an omitted word

> We sat on the corner of the restaurant talking [about] how blessed we were for having a new house.

or missing punctuation.

> We sat on the corner of the restaurant talking.  How blessed we were, for having a new house.

The "and" in (2) doesn't really change the rest of the problem.